# Recursion and multiplication

Tags: java, recursion, multiplication

Is this possible guys? This is homework I have, and my teacher obviously believes it is, but it seems to me that it's impossible not to use addition or multiplication outside of the short-multiplication method.

> Write  (and provide a tester for) a recursive algorithm:
>
> int multiply(int x, int y)
>
> to multiply two positive integers together without using the *
>   operator. Do not just add x to itself y times!!!
>
> (Hint: Write a recursive method that will multiply an integer by a
>   value in the range 0 .. 10. Then write a second recursive method to
>   implement the multiplication algorithm you learned to multiply
>   multi-digit numbers in elementary school.)

My issue is that once you break down any multi digit number and starting adding those together you have to use multiplication of numbers greater than 10, i.e 22 * 6 is 2 * 6 + 20 * 6 ... so am I totally missing something?

**EDIT**
I guess I should have added this is the code I have,

```
public int mult(int x, int y){
return x == 0 ? 0 : (mult(x-1, y) + y);
}
```

which is perfect, but as far as I understand the instructions, that's breaking do not just add x to itself y times. I personally believe it isn't, but my teacher hasn't been very clear, and I'd like to know if there's some other way that I havn't thought of, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It's very possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Please update this if the instructor had a different solution then the given recursive functions.

Comment: I will, it will take a few days though since it's not actually due till this evening.

Comment: still havn't gotten the answer, incase anyone wants to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation of the assignment is that the teacher would like the student to implement a recursive algorithm to perform [Grid method multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_method_multiplication) (the kind we learn in elementary school).

For example, multiplying 34 x 13 would be done like so...

```
  34
* 13
====
  12
  90
  40
+300
====
 442
```

I didn't have easy access to a Java development environment, so I wrote the code in C# but the algorithm should be simple enough to convert into Java.

```
public int Multiply(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 0) throw new ArgumentException("must be positive integer", "x");
    if (y < 0) throw new ArgumentException("must be positive integer", "y");

    if (x == 0 || y == 0) return 0; // obvious quick-exit condition

    // integer division
    int xDivBy10 = x / 10;
    int yDivBy10 = y / 10;

    bool xIsSingleDigit = xDivBy10 == 0;
    bool yIsSingleDigit = yDivBy10 == 0;

    // base case
    if (xIsSingleDigit && yIsSingleDigit)
    {
        return MultiplySingleDigits(x, y);
    }

    // otherwise, use grid multiplication recursively
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_method_multiplication

    if (xIsSingleDigit) // y must not be a single digit
    {
        return (Multiply(x, yDivBy10) * 10) + Multiply(x, y % 10);
    }

    if (yIsSingleDigit) // x must not be a single digit
    {
        return (Multiply(xDivBy10, y) * 10) + Multiply(x % 10, y);
    }

    // else - x and y are both numbers which are not single digits
    return (Multiply(x, yDivBy10) * 10) + Multiply(x, y % 10); // the same code as the "if (xIsSingleDigit)" case
}

// technically, this algorith can multiply any positive integers
// but I have restricted it to only single digits as per the assignment's requirements/hint
private int MultiplySingleDigits(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 0 || x > 9) throw new ArgumentException("must be in range 0 - 9 (inclusive)", "x");
    if (y < 0 || y > 9) throw new ArgumentException("must be in range 0 - 9 (inclusive)", "y");

    if (x == 0 || y == 0) return 0; // base case
    return x + MultiplySingleDigits(x, y - 1);
}
```

**NOTES:**

- This approach still uses the `*` operator but not for actually multiplying `x` and `y`, it is used to increase other sub-products by multiples of 10
- Many parts of this code could be simplified/refactored but I specifically left them expanded to make the steps more obvious

Comment: So this is what I was implying, but I still don't really see how it's all that different, cause i'm still adding something to itself some other number of times. Anyway, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: From the sounds of the assignment, the instructor isn't looking for efficiency; they are more interested in making you think about the algorithmic steps. I still am not certain this is what they were looking for (because it uses the `*` operator and theprivate method still uses the algorithm that you already came up with) but it seems closest to what the teacher is after.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible.  Yes, I think you're missing something.  Try writing down the steps you'd follow to manually multiply two numbers, the way you learned in elementary school.

Then turn those steps into code.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do it.

First of all, think about the condition. If some number is 0, then the result is? Right.. zero.

So.. You'll have `if x is zero or y is zero return 0`

Now.. saying X * Y is like saying *"X, Y times"*, which is like writing: X + .... + X (Y times).

So, you'll have something like:

```
x + multiply(x, y - 1);
```

You'll have to consider the case in which one of the numbers is negative (But if you understand the basic, I believe you can easily do it).

Comment: how is that not "Do not just add x to itself y times"?

Comment: I believe he is telling him not to use loops.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will work for both when y>=0 and y<0

```
public int multiply(final int x, final int y) {
    if (y != 0 && x != 0) {
        if (y > 0) {
            return multiply(x, y - 1) + x;
        } else {
            return multiply(x, y + 1) - x;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does this meet `Do not just add x to itself y times`?

Answer (score 0):

Easily possible.

```
int multiply(int x, int y) {
    if(y == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return x + multiply(x, y - 1);
}
```

The above fails to take into account the case where y is negative, but you wouldn't want me to do all your work for you . . .

Comment: how is that not "Do not just add x to itself y times"?

Comment: I'm assuming that instruction refers to for loops.

Comment: yea, that's my issue I thought originally he meant just don't iterate, but now i'm not so sure

Comment: @Connor have you asked him?

Comment: yea, the whole class had a discussion about it...my interpretation was that he meant even that recursive version was just adding x + x  y times, but now that I think about it maybe it was just about iteration...class is kinda noisy. Anyway unless someone has some other idea i'm just going to say that's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    static int Multiply(int x, int y)
    {
        if (y > 0 && x > 0)
            return (x + Multiply(x, y - 1));
        if (y < 0 && x > 0)
            return -Multiply(x, -y);
        if (x < 0 && y > 0)
            return -Multiply(-x, y);
        if (x < 0 && y < 0)
            return Multiply(-x, -y);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for your first answer.

To make the answer more useful to other people, it is best practice to annotate your answer with text that explains why it addresses the OP's original question.

Comment: How does this meet `Do not just add x to itself y times`?